# Customising URL paths using Navigation Guards

Tags: javascript, routes, vuejs3, vue-router

I have an application with two pages.

**Page one:**

```
<form>
    <input pattern="\d*" maxlength="4" v-model="id" required>
    <router-link :to="`/${id}`">
       <div @click="info">GET</div>
    </router-link>
</form>
```

Using `('0000' + this.id).slice(-4)`, I am able to transfer 4 digits to 2nd page with desired URL like:

- input:1, navigated to: http://127.0.0.1:3000/0001
- input:321 => navigated to: http://127.0.0.1:3000/0321

***Note:** At the moment, I can pass the letters also because I am not validating*

My question is how to use the `next({path: ''})` Navigation Guards. I want the following to happen:

- input:http://127.0.0.1:3000/1, automatically redirected as: http://127.0.0.1:3000/0001
- input:http://127.0.0.1:3000/99, automatically redirected as: http://127.0.0.1:3000/0099

I tried using `beforeEnter`, but I think I am missing some things. This is my route.js file.

```
const routes=[
    {
        name:'Info',
        path:'/:id',
        component: Info,
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {     
            to.params.myCustomizations = {
                id_num: ('0000' + to.params.id).slice(-4)     
            }
            next({path: `/${to.params.myCustomizations}`})
          },
    },
];
```

I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```js
to.params.myCustomizations = {
    id_num: ('0000' + to.params.id).slice(-4)     
}
next({path: `/${to.params.myCustomizations}`})
```

You should write:

```js
next({path: `/${('0000' + to.params.id).slice(-4)}`})
```

Or:

```js
to.params.id = ('0000' + to.params.id).slice(-4)
next()
```

Ps: Why the padded id? The number would be good by itself.

Comment: Dear Geri, 
Thank you for your kind reply.
The reason I am padding it is because of such a requirement. Anyhow, I have figured out a way to solve it by strictly having an id of length 4. e.g., 22 is invalid where al 0022 is valid. 

I tried your solution, but It doesn't work. But I will try to fix it somehow. 

Thank you again.